# Math equations software for 3D plotting

Tags: linux, graphs, math, 3d

Is there a GUI based software that I can use to plot functions in 3D under Linux?

Something with no frills but numerically correct, for example the "grapher" application under Mac OS is handy, but is often times incorrect and generating weird graphs.

Comment: How strict is your GUI restriction? And are you willing to pay for it?

Comment: @Bernhard I have to investigate the numerical behaviour of some formulas, mainly about trigonometry and linear algebra, I don't know what you mean with "GUI restriction" but I would like to have no clutter, just a box where I put my formulas and a section where the the software will display the resulting 3D plot, I don't think I'll need nothing more than that. My focus is also on parametric surfaces and parametric construction of 3D objects, so I really need to visualize that.

Comment: Well, gnuplot has no GUI, but you noted in one of your comments that it would be an alternative. I don't see what is wrong with Gnuplot by the way.

Comment: @Bernhard gnuplot offers a GUI, it's limited, but you can do the basic stuff, like rotating or moving the 3D object. Also gnuplot, for what I know, uses octave as a backend for the computation, which means that you can you octave in the first place and obtain pretty much the same numerical results since octave now offers a native GUI too.

Comment: Ah, that is what you mean by GUI. Than I would add it as an answer, but seems a bit unnecessary. Gnuplot does not use Octave by the way. (maybe the other way around?)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/):

- free
- works with Windows/Macintosh/Linux
- has a GUI since Octave 3.8

[image]

Comment: this is octave workshop, it's not octave.

Comment: @user2485710 image fixed

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3d%20plot):

- free (unless you need advanced features)
- web service

[image]

If you want to use it off-line, you can use [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/):

- non-free
- works with Windows/Macintosh/Linux

[image]

Comment: no thanks, this doesn't meet my requirements

Comment: @user2485710 Which requirement isn't met?

Comment: the first it's an online solution that doesn't cut it and surely it's not an IDE, The second one is certainly not a good option either since it's cumbersome a not free, at this point I would just go with octave or gnuplot.

Comment: @user2485710 add free as a requirement then.

Comment: @user2485710 Gnuplot does not have a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/):

- Free (+ [portable version available](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/portable))
- Works with Windows/Mac/Linux (even Android/iPhone/Windows Phone as well as in Google Chrome)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**mathmod**
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mathmod/

[image]

Description
MathMod is a mathematical modeling software that visualize and animate implicit and parametric surfaces.
MathMod supports:
3D and 4D plotting and animation
OBJ output file format
Scripting language in JSON file format
Textue and pigmentation support
Noise and Turbulence effects support
Large set of scripted examples

Answer (score 1):

http://k3dsurf.sourceforge.net/

[image]
K3DSurf is a program for visualizing and manipulating multidimensional surfaces by using Mathematical equations. It's also a "modeler" for POV-Ray in the area of parametric surfaces. It features 3D, 4D, 5D, and 6D HyperObjects visualization, full support for all functions (like the C language), support for mouse events in the drawing area, animation and morph effects, Povscript and mesh file generation, and support for VRML2 and OBJ files. More than 100 examples are provided.