# Is there any good editor for 3D math scenes?

Tags: math, 3d, modeling

I was wondering if there is any useful editor for 3D math scenes out there. Something in style of a 3D editor like Blender, but with functionality like adding a line, plane or plot a function like in MATLAB.

There are some kind of function plotters like the [Online 3-D Function Grapher](http://www.livephysics.com/tools/mathematical-tools/online-3-d-function-grapher/) and of course Wolfram|Alpha, but is there an editor where I can build whole scenes by myself?

**Edit:** I implemented a Web app by myself, cause nothing was close to my needs. You can give it a try under: http://math.zumschlenker.de/

Comment: How about [Math equations software for 3D plotting](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2822/903)?

Comment: I don't only need the plotting task, more something like GeoGebra. Thanks ;)

Comment: You might want to create an answer for your own software (with a disclaimer that you are the developer).

Comment: The web app you wrote is amazing!  Quite impressive.  Perhaps you can add formulaic curves to it (like sine cubed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/):

- Free (+ [portable version available](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/en/portable))
- Works with Windows/Mac/Linux (even Android/iPhone/Windows Phone as well as in Google Chrome)
- Can do 3D plotting:

[image]

Comment: How can I switch in 3D space?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Visual Python](http://vpython.org/index.html), it is a free 3D tool with lots of examples of using and displaying 3D maths functions.